# Opening file in Remote Database

Tags: java, database, file

I have java desktop application where I have file upload and view feature.
Here is my code for opening a file

```
 public static boolean open(File file) {
    OSDetector osdetector = new OSDetector();
    try {
        if (osdetector.isWindows()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"rundll32", "url.dll,FileProtocolHandler",
                file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else if (osdetector.isLinux() || osdetector.isMac()) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/usr/bin/open",
                file.getAbsolutePath()});
            return true;
        } else // Unknown OS, try with desktop
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is perfectly working in MAC OS but when I am running in windows 7 PC it won't open files.
Following are the error messages;

**Adobe reader error:** "There was an error opening this document. This file is already open or in use by another application"

**Windows Photo viewer error message:** "Windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the picture is being edited in another program"

**Paint error message:** "A sharing violation occurred while accessing ....."

Please help

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows can't cope with the idea of two programs using a file at once, presumably due to its DOS single-user origins. Make sure that when you save the file, you close it *before* you call your `open()` method.